# Post-processing the output result from Dymola when there are only 2 elements in the result

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to use the MATLAB scripts shipped with Dymola to post-process the output result of Dymola. But in some cases, the output data in the .mat file only have 2 elements, how could I get the data between 10s and 100s in this kind of cases?

It's a parameter or variable that is not time depending so it's stored in a compact way. I understand the mechanism, but it is not user-friendly when post-processing the data in MATLAB, I have to find the "wrong" dimensional data. How could I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: As you said, its a constant value. You could check if the parameter is constant and convert the 2 element array to a scalar value. Therefore you dont have to deal with the actual dimension of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating some simple logic that looks at the size of the variable and then automatically puts it into some dictionary, list, etc. From there you can manipulate the variable. I know you are asking for Matlab but here is a Python solution that I have used which may help you get started:

```
    varNames_param_base=[]
    varNames_var_base=[]
    for i, val in enumerate(r.varNames()):
        if np.size(r.values(val)) == 4:
            varNames_param_base.append(val)
        else:      
            varNames_var_base.append(val)
```

I used those lines in this [file](https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/ModelicaPy/blob/master/modelicapy/cleanData.py).

In the example `r.varNames()` is a list of all the variable names (i.e., strings) which are read from the resulting Dymola `.mat` file. `r.values` gets the value of the variable name currently being used in the for loop (i.e., `val`).

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider converting your result file to SDF (a simple HDF5 representation), because that format does not use any clever storage options (if I remember correctly).